# openvpn bandwidth and ping fluctuations

Tags: linux, performance, openvpn, bandwidth

Good day all

I have recently setup an OpenVPN server (which I have done in the past, a few times),

this server has a 1 Gbps connection, however using a standard openvpn server/client config,

Speedtest Beta shows bandwidth results of 12Mbps and 7Mbps over wifi, these are max values from multiple tests, avg test results are: down 5-7Mbps, up 6-7Mbps and cpu load is <5% at testing time, this was tested over a institution WiFi(Wireless-N) aswel as a cat 5e cable with speedtest over 500Mbps up/down.

Server type and OS: OpenVZ - Ubuntu 15.04; hardware - 2 vCPU with 512Mb ram

It feels like something is capping my OpenVPN connection, this was also tested over multiple devices (2 Windows, 2 Android) confirming the same results

Any recommendations/solutions?

**EDIT**

UDP - 123
lzo compression diabled (enabled slowed it down, fairly)
using default cipher (BF)

Comment: Do you use TCP to transport OpenVPN procol?

Comment: apologies, see edit

Comment: Try testing with [iperf](https://iperf.fr/) then monitor the kernel networking parameters and see which you are maxing out.  You may want to increase TCP window sizes or find another bottleneck.